# Angular input[type=date]. No value showed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker

I have issue with angular `date` inputs.

Example code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
  angular.module('app', []).controller('ACtrlr', function($scope){
    $scope.start = new Date();
    $scope.plusDay = function(s){
      console.log(s);
      $scope.start.setDate($scope.start.getDate() + 1);
    };
  });
</script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ACtrlr">
  <input type="date" ng-model="start" />
  <input type="date" ng-model="start" />
  {{start}}
  <button ng-click="plusDay(start)" >+</button>
</div>
```

If I change this programmaticaly(click a button first), model changes correctly, but no values in inputs presented.
If I change date input immediately, model becomes simple text like `2014-12-29` and all brakes.

Earlier I used this with text values only, but now I get [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngModel/datefmt?p0=2014-12-29) exception.

Knows anybody what's wrong here? And what is correct way to work with `input[type=date]`s?

---

*Google Chrome 38.0.2125.111 (64-bit)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> note that this feature (input['date']) is not works in older angular versions. its working angular 1.3 and onward

please check the breaking changes in angularjs change log [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#130-rc4-unicorn-hydrafication-2014-10-01)

and updating this will solve your problem, with a newer version of angularjs. here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RFajc9eyOw7VJAyIyIZ2?p=preview)

```
$scope.plusDay = function(s){
  console.log(s);
  $scope.start.setDate($scope.start.getDate() + 1);
  $scope.start = new Date($scope.start);
};
```

Comment: I can't to understand what wrong :( I use `{full: "1.3.8", major: 1, minor: 3, dot: 8, codeName: "prophetic-narwhal"}` angular version from bower... How can I debug this?

Comment: Great thanks for links, I check last commits and see, that `date` filter used for values showing. And I have my own `date` filter, which makes me screwed :) Thanks.